# Declaring same css for more than one id?

Tags: css

How do I do it.

```
#foo, #ball, #tree h1 {color: #892828;}
```

Does not seem to work?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What is the HTML this is being applied to, what are you expecting, and what do you actually see? And for good measure, which browsers have you tested?

Comment: I have several ids assigned to different body tags for those pages, I simply want to apply a style to the H1 element for those H1. And doesn't work in any of the broswers. I am writing in HTML5 if that makes a difference? Thanks.

Comment: This was helpful.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

if you want to style all H1 under those Ids, you have to repeat H1 for every one as they don't share anything:

```
#foo h1, #ball h1, #tree h1 {color: #892828;}
```

what you wrote is equivalent to:

```
#foo {color: #892828;}
#ball {color: #892828;}
#tree h1 {color: #892828;}
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks. How do you mean by share anything, how come sometimes I can use my example above on some elements and it works?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You could also assign the same class to each of those h1s and style using that class.

Answer (score 0):

```
:is(#foo, #ball, #tree) h1 {color: #892828;}
```

This approach works with any ID, no need for prefixing and attribute selectors. The CSS pseudo-class [:is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) is now supported by all major browsers.